# Add increment index number in a collection

Tags: c#, collections

```
public class Comment
{
    public int IndexNo {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedOn {get;set;}
}

static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    var comments = new List<Comment>()
    {
        new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1) },
        new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2) },
        new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3) },
        new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4) },
    };

    // Not very nice solution..
    var foos = new List<Comment>();
    foreach(var foo in comments.orderby(c=> c.createdOn))
    {
        foo.IndexNo = ++i;
        foos.add(foo);
    }

}
```

How do I assign some increment number to the IndexNo properties, from the list?
My expected output is:

- 15 April 2004 2:37pm ~ 1
- 15 April 2004 2:38pm ~ 2
- 15 April 2004 2:39pm ~ 3
- 15 April 2004 2:40pm ~ 4

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to order here? the data is already sorted... if you want to order it by something other than their existing order, then your "Not very nice solution" is actually pretty reasonable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want to modify the existing objects inside the collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comments.Count; ++i)
    comments[i].IndexNo = i+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Re comment:

> Actually I was hoping to assign the increment IndexNo, after the collection has been created.

then just loop:

```
int i = 1;
foreach(var comment in comments) comment.IndexNo = i++;
```

---

Since you are hard-coding the offset, you could just hard-code:

```
var comments = new List<Comment>() {
    new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), IndexNo = 1 },
    new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), IndexNo = 2 },
    new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3), IndexNo = 3 },
    new Comment() { CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(4), IndexNo = 4 },
};
```

If you want something less hard-coded, how about:

```
var comments = (from i in Enumerable.Range(1,4)
                select new Comment {
                   CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i), IndexNo = i
                }).ToList();
```

or simpler:

```
var comments = new List<Comment>(4);
for(int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    comments.Add(new Comment {
         CreatedOn = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i), IndexNo = i });
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Maybe my question not very clear. Actually I was hoping to assign the increment IndexNo, after the collection has been created.

Comment: @hypokerit then... just loop: `int i = 1; foreach(var comment in comments) comment.IndexNo = i++;`